# How to detect change in pdf loaded using PDF KIT iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, pdfkit

I have loaded an editable pdf in iOS. But not able to figure out if user have done any changes to that pdf.

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PdfFormExample" ofType:@"pdf"]];
PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:fileData];
PDFView *pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
pdfView.document = pdfDocument
[self.view addSubView:pdfView];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDFKit for controlling and loading the pdf into iOS app. Its provided by the apple. In that you have to first setup delegate for the PDFs

`PDFDocumentDelegate`

- PDFKit can send the notifications for different operations such as begin writing, end writing, etc. So you can use these methods to get local notification get determine that whether the user started writing or modifying the PDF. For that you can use,

`PDFDocumentDidBeginPageWriteNotification
 PDFDocumentDidEndPageWriteNotification`

any of the above according to when you wanna make changes.

If you want more reference to this here is the link:

[PDFKit / PDF Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument?language=objc)

Comment: while start editing these notification not triggering .

Comment: you have to setup delegate to file you are using the PDFKit and 

PDFDocumentDidBeginPageWriteNotification
is just a delegate method. you have to create separate notification and pass it as the argument to this method and this method will trigger that notification when someone starts writing.

Comment: you are still not clear. PDFDocumentDidBeginPageWriteNotification  is notification which is not triggering while editing. I went through all delagate methods non of them get called while editing .

Comment: I d'ont really understand how this works, as Shaik Riyaz said, no notification is triggered, "PDFDocumentDidBeginPageWriteNotification is just a delegate method" make no sens to me since no method this name in the PDFDocumentDelegate protocole. Can you put a code sample ?